# Android - 5.0 Lollipop touch highlight with state selected setting

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I used drawable/touch_highlight.xml for my touch view, and has been using in view fine below Android 4.4. How to get it work on 5.0 Lollipop.

use in layout

```
android:background="@drawable/touch_highlight"
```

touch_highlight.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/lightGreen"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. Can you include more context around the layout XML?

Answer (score 1):

To let touch highlight present, add this in ListView to show ripple effect.

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

For more info: [Listview selector with colored background and ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443496/listview-selector-with-colored-background-and-ripple-effect)