# RecyclerView onclick not showing Ripple Effect or Highlight

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following item xml and the drawable for the item element.
I am not seeing ripple effect when I click the list item.

my_recycler_view_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/main_row"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/button_rect_list_normal"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hisTrainNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:text="Train No" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hisTrainName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:text="Train Name" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hisFrom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:text="From" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hisTo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="To" />

</LinearLayout>
```

button_rect_list_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/green"
    >
</ripple>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443496/listview-selector-with-colored-background-and-ripple-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working finally using this famous library. This library is very simple and easy to integrate!
https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect