# Listview item ripple showing over cell hiding contents

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, ripple

I am trying to show a ripple effect on Lollipop devices when the user clicks on a cell in a listview. Based on the post at  [Listview selector with colored background and ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443496/listview-selector-with-colored-background-and-ripple-effect?rq=1) I did the same as suggested with `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`, however with this after the ripple is shown the background color is shown over the cell thus hiding the contents of the cell completely.

So would like to know if there is any proper way to achieve the ripple effect on the individual items in a listview?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified a custom background for the items in the ListView? If so, then you need to create two drawables for your background, one in the "drawable" folder and the other in the "drawable-v21" folder.

For example, if the file name of the drawable is "list_item_bg.xml", then

/drawable-v21/list_item_bg.xml would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/accent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and /drawable/list_item_bg.xml would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/dark_accent" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/accent" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/accent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: still appears the same :(

Comment: could you post the code for the layout of your list item?

Comment: I used the same one you pasted above